# how to customizely replace dbunit's dataset Object

Tags: java, dbunit

I am struggling to create a custom `DateTime` object that looks like this:

```
  2015-05-07 12:12:00 - > [the date is today's date but the time is custom]
```

I have a junit test class with dbunit's dataset, I have been able to use ReplacementDataSet's classes addReplacementObject() method to replace a placeholder like [NOW] with today's date, but i have hard time to figure out 
how to replace the date part of `DateTime` object while keeping the time. Can any body help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think dbunit can do this far. but you can use another approach. From my prespective i would rather prefer to do the insertion of customized datetime in my test class rather than puting in dbunit dataset. If your dao class has a functionality to insert the date , you can create a TimeStamp object as show below:

```
    DateTime dt= new DateTime();

    Timestamp timeStamp=new Timestamp(dt.withTime(12,12,0,0).getMillis())
```

After creating this object , you can safely uset it in your query. I hope this to be helpfull.

**NB**: i am using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library to create thed Date time object. it is very powerfull and currently it is the de facto standard date and time library for Java