# How to set current date in yaml file

Tags: java, postgresql, yaml, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I am creating a dataset in yml format to initialize a table in a postgresql database

```
- id : 5
    description : "test5"
    is_deleted : false
    last_redaction_date : 2021-12-13 15:09:52.715570
    persist_date : 2022-03-02 15:09:52.715570
    title : "test5"
    user_id : 15
```

How can I set the current date in the required format to the persist_date variable so as not to manually enter the date each time?

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(classes = JmApplication.class)
public class TestQuestionResourceController extends AbstractClassForDRRiderMockMVCTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

      @Test
      @DataSet(cleanBefore = true,
                value = {
                        "dataset/testQuestionResourceController/question_different_date.yml",
                   
                },
                strategy = SeedStrategy.CLEAN_INSERT
        )
        public void getQuestionSortedByWeightForTheWeek() throws Exception {
```

Comment: Which part are you stuck on, how to get the current date and time, how to format it, or how to update the yaml?

Comment: how to get the current date and time, how to format it

Comment: It seems this is more to do with modifying a [tag:dbunit] `@DataSet` on the fly than to do with formatting dates or writing yaml, although formatting dates may be a sub-task. See [Is there any way I can specify the current system time for my testcase?](https://www.dbunit.org/faq.html#systemTimeInTest) and maybe [how to customizely replace dbunit's dataset Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30100467/how-to-customizely-replace-dbunits-dataset-object). I'm not really familiar with dbunit but perhaps others are.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current date and time from [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html):

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
```

And then you can format the time using [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)'s `ISO_LOCAL_DATE` and `ISO_LOCAL_TIME`:

```
String currentDateTime = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.format(now) +
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME.format(now);
```

Which produces `"2022-03-14 12:40:32.8071372"`.

Comment: and where did I write this code so that the variable was visible in the yml file?

Comment: @adil_screamyy I thought you weren't stuck on how to update the yaml?

Comment: help pleas, I'm new at this

Comment: You would have to show the code where you're creating the yaml.